# How to split a cell in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have created a cell in html5 and I would to split the cell I have tried using `colspan="2"` but it does not fit what I want to achieve.

What I want to do is, split the cell like shown in the image below where the left side allows the user to type in text and right side is a button that when clicked toggles the word ON/OFF.

[image]
https://jsfiddle.net/kmkgr4ru/

Sorry if my question is not clear, I am fairly new to web development. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: cant you set width do say 80/20 ?

Comment: No, you can't *split* a cell...but you can put two elements in a cell.

Answer (score 0):

`colspan` makes a single cell take up multiple columns. You are trying to use it in reverse.

Make the matching cells on the *other rows* span columns instead.

```css
table,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo
    <td colspan="2">Bar
  <tr>
    <td>Baz
    <td><input>
    <td><button>On</button>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer is it possible to place the button along a div tag instead of input please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do following way:

```js
$("#btnToggle").click(function () {
            $(this).text(function(i, val){
               return val === 'ON' ? 'OFF' : 'ON'
            })
        });
```

```css
td {
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
}


div {
    margin-right: 50px;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
  <td><div contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</div>
  <button id='btnToggle'>ON</button>
  </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmkgr4ru/4/)**

**Solution 2:**

And if you don't want to use `position:absolute` then `display:flex` do the trick.

```js
$("#btnToggle").click(function () {
            $(this).text(function(i, val){
               return val === 'ON' ? 'OFF' : 'ON'
            })
        });
```

```css
td {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    position: relative;
}
div {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
  <td><div contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</div>
  <button id='btnToggle'>ON</button>
  </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/kmkgr4ru/5/)**